# Form submission not processed in Django

Tags: python, django

I wrote the following code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Contact{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="mdc-layout-grid">
    <div class="mdc-layout-grid__inner">
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-1">
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-5">
            <h4 class="mdc-typography--headline4">Get in Touch!</h4>
            <br/>

        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-5">
            <h4 class="mdc-typography--headline4">Contact Us!</h4>
            <br/>
            <div class="mdc-card mdc-card-outlined mdc-card-shaped">
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% load widget_tweaks %}
                    <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--fullwidth">
                        {% render_field form.name class+="mdc-text-field__input" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--fullwidth">
                        {% render_field form.email class+="mdc-text-field__input" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--fullwidth">
                        {% render_field form.phone class+="mdc-text-field__input" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--textarea mdc-text-field--fullwidth">
                        {% render_field form.question class+="mdc-text-field__input" id="question" type="text" placeholder="Question" row=8 col=10 %}
                        <div class="mdc-notched-outline">
                            <div class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></div>
                            <div class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised" type="submit">  <span class="mdc-button__ripple"></span> Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

With the following class based view method:

```
class ContactCreate(CreateView):
    model = Contact

    fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'question']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('contact')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Your inquiry has been received!')

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And the following line in the URLs file:

```
path('contact', views.contact.ContactCreate.as_view(template_name="contact.html"), name='contact'),
```

Somehow when I submit the form on the page the page simply reloads and nothing else happens. The console output of Django is the following:

```
[19/Dec/2019 23:20:16] "POST /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 9044
```

When I check the database the entry is not there. What could cause this issue

Comment: You make a GET request, not a POST request.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My bad added the correct console output line; [19/Dec/2019 23:20:16] "POST /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 9044

Comment: It looks like it is not triggering the `ContactCreate` view. Normally a POST request returns a 301 status code, not a 200.